# Gradle build on Android Studio is taking around 40 min when project folder resides in Desktop Mac OS BigSur

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image]I am running on `Android Studio 4.1.1` with `16 gb mac book pro` I have only `one Module` in my Android App, I am not using any third party library , when i build the project its taking more than 40 min to finish the build execution , If you look at my `gradle.properties` i have mentioned below

```
org.gradle.daemon=true


org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8


org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.configureondemand=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Here i am attaching my snap from `[![Build Analyser][1]][1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the issue what causing the issue in my case here are the below steps i have tried so far -> changed `gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip from `5.6.4`
```

then updated the Android Gradle version in my `Android Studio to 4.X.X` and the changed suggested by @Narendra_Nath on above comment nothing working for me.

I was running the App on Android Studio Latest `version 4.2.1` on Mac book 16gb ram Big Sur -> I tried the above steps nothing worked.

I found the issue latter for some reason if your project is in desktop it's taking more than 45 min to do `gradle build` on `Macbook BigSur`

> then i moved the project to `user` boom it worked build with in 2 min

.

Answer (score 0):

Do these things

1. add `org.gradle.caching=true` add `org.gradle.daemon=true`
   If you have two variants of your app in the dev variant disable pngcrunching and disable it such that instead of searching for appropriate image it searches for a particular image itself(xxhdpi)

in your dev block in gradle add these two lines `splits.abi.enable=false` and
`splits.density.enable=false`

Optimize your firebase crashalytics if you're using it.
[Also see the google talk on improving Gradle builds][1]

I improved my gradle time from 17 minutes to 9 following the above practices.
Make sure you have offlinegradle button clicked in the gradle tab to the right of the screen.
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ll-rkLCtyk

Comment: png crunching is by default enable in debug mode i.e when you running on emulator or device and you can see i have mentioned org.gradle.daemon=true now i added org.gradle.caching=true the result is same

Comment: Updated the answer. Pls check

Comment: Which dev block you are referring this in your dev block in gradle add these two lines spilits.abi.enable=false and splits.density.enable=false

Comment: in the app level Gradle, you should have a dev and release variant

Comment: i added dev{
            splits.abi.enable=false
            splits.density.enable=false
        } but no difference

Comment: please do a fresh build with invalidate caches and restart and then build it once. It should change . if it doesn't it might be a system limitation

Comment: Please check my answer above